# How to refer button name using mutual events in WinForms?

Tags: visual-studio, c#

I have a simple code below and I want, if `button1` clicked then `textBox` changed to `button1 is clicked`. And if `button2` clicked then `textBox` changed to `button2 is clicked`.

But I want to refer current function's name (button1_Click or button2_Click).

In `Form1 [Design]` page. In there, Events page using little arrow `mutual events`.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = this.Name + "is clicked"; 
                // "this" isn't work. I think it'd Form1. How to button1 and button2
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sender` parameter contains the details you want, you just need to first cast it to a `Button`

```
this.textBox1.Text = (sender as Button).Text;
```

Ideally you would actually implement null value checking, just in case the method is used elsewhere by something which is not as button!  Then you would have

```
if ((sender as Button) != null)
    this.textBox1.Text = (sender as Button).Text;
```

Make sure that the same click event is added to every button where you want this functionality.